# App hidden by device owner is not listed as installed

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, device-owner

I am recently playing around with Device Owner features of Android M and more specific with [hiding apps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setApplicationHidden(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean))

After hiding a package, it does not show as installed anymore from package manager:
`context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)`
or
`adb shell pm list packages`

Is there an alternative way of listing those packages?

A similar feature on Samsung MDM SDK actually `disables` the app instead of hiding them, so it stops responding to query intents but still lists on installed packages.

Comment: Hi Filipe, The samsung mdm sdk you are referring to works only on samsung devices right?

Comment: Yes. (https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/knox-standard-android/api-references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a way of fetching the info I needed through `adb`:

List all active pacakges:

`adb shell pm list packages`

List all packages including uninstalled but with local files (hidden):

`adb shell pm list packages -u`

Only hidden packages:

`fgrep -v -f <(adb shell pm list packages |sort) <(adb shell pm list packages -u|sort)`